# How to access all the row data when sending this

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, html-table, this

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>McDonalds</td>
  <td><a href="" onclick="delete(this)"><img src="delete.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

function delete(this)
{
   //how to access all the data from this row (id,name,lastname)
}
```

Comment: those are just text. so this could help you `$(this).closest('tr').text()`.

Comment: how to get each of the cells in that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to separate HTML from Jquery or javascript and work with events:

Add a selector in your HTML like `delete`:

```
<td><a href="#" class="delete"><img src="delete.png"/></a></td>
```

And then just select the row and the columns you want to work with using [eq function](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
$('.delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //disallowing the link

    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var td = row.find('td');

    var id = td.eq(0).text();  //first column
    var lastName = td.eq(1).text();  //second column
    var options = td.eq(2).text();  //third column

    alert("id: " + id +"\n" + "lastName: " + lastName + "\n" + "Options: " + options);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7c4E3/

Alternatively you can make use of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5991132/1081396) to create an array of data if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add classes on those columns? If it is, try this:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">1</td>
        <td class="name">John</td>
        <td class="lastname">McDonalds</td>
        <td><a class="deleteRow" href="#" onclick=""><img src="delete.png"/></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".deleteRow").click(function (e) {
    var thisrow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = thisrow.find(".id").text();
    var name = thisrow.find(".name").text();
    var lastname = thisrow.find(".lastname").text();
    alert("You selected " + id + ": " + name + " " + lastname);
});
```

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GJW3U/)**

Answer (score 0):

Then i suggest you to try with jQuery way:

Here `.del` is the class name of the delete button and you can find that by `.eq()` function which selects elements by their indexes.

```
$('.del').on('click', function(){
   var theRow = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
   var id = theRow.eq(0).text();
   var fName = theRow.eq(1).text();
   var lName = theRow.eq(2).text();
   console.log(id + ' ' + fName + ' '+ lName);
});
```