# How to get all values in <tr> of html <table>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get all values of td when I click the checkbox which is fourth coloumn.
Also I want to get the smallest among ID and Optional ID

```
<table><form method='GET'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Optional ID</th>
<th>Approved</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sumit</td>
<td>4</td>
<td><input type='text' name='txt`[]' /></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' /></td>
</tr>`
<tr>
<td>Harsh</td>
<td>3</td>
<td><input type='text' name='txt`[]' /></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' /></td>
</tr>`
<tr><td colspan=4><input type='submit' name='sub1' /></td></tr>    
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991011/getting-all-the-table-td-values-into-array.   Refer this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
function Start() {

    $('#SubmitBtn').click(function () {

        $('#TheTable').find('tr').each(function () {

            if ($(this).find('input').eq(1).is(':checked') === true) {

                alert($(this).find('input').val());
            }

        });
    });
}

$(Start);
```

There's a jsFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/e76vw17e/)**