# Collect <td> strings into an Array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have some tabular data and I need to put them into an array so I can look for a match elsewhere in the code.  So I need to convert this:

```
<td> Name 1 </td>
<td> Name 2 </td>
<td> Name 3 </td>
```

into:

```
['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']
```

This does not work:

```
 $('td').text().toArray();
```

I really hoped it would :)  I need to take the text of an input and compare it to the existing `<td>`s to make sure it's unique, so if there is a better way of going about it, I'd love to hear it.  I know I could create an empty array, create a loop or use $.each() and push() each .text() to the array, but there has got to be a more concise way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all the table td values into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991011/getting-all-the-table-td-values-into-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [**`map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method like following.

```js
var arr = $('td').map(function (){
    return $(this).text().trim();
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Name 1 </td>
        <td> Name 2 </td>
        <td> Name 3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah I never quite grasped the .map() and .get().  Thanks!

Comment: @Azim maybe you can tell me - when do you know when .get() will be necessary?  I know the documentation says .get() "Retrieves the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object".  So when you have a matched set returned from a normal jQuery selector, how do you know you also need to then do a .get() to "retrieve" the items already in the matched set?

Comment: `map()` returns a jQuery object. `get()` returns an array containing each element in a jQuery object (plain JS array). @SpaceNinja

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the elements and get each one's text. In plain js you could do :

```js
var result = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("td"), function(el) {
        return el.innerHTML.trim();
    });

    console.log(result)
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Name 1 </td>
        <td> Name 2 </td>
        <td> Name 3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```